# ctypes pointer question

Tags: python, object, pointers, declaration, ctypes

I was reading the ctypes tutorial, and I came across this:

```
s = "Hello, World"
c_s = c_char_p(s)
print c_s
c_s.value = "Hi, there"
```

But I had been using pointers like this:

```
s = "Hello, World!"
c_s = c_char_p()
c_s = s
print c_s
c_s.value

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    c_s.value
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Why is it that when I do it one way, I can access c_s.value, and when I do it the other way, there is no value object?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example, you've got the statements:

```
c_s = c_char_p()
c_s = s
```

The `ctypes` module can't break the [rules of Python assignments](http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html), and in the above case the second assignment *rebinds* the `c_s` name from the just-created `c_char_p` object to the `s` object. In effect, this throws away the newly created `c_char_p` object, and your code produces the error in your question because a regular Python string doesn't have a `.value` property.

Try instead:

```
c_s = c_char_p()
c_s.value = s
```

and see whether that aligns with your expectations.

Comment: Ohh. Wow, that's a great fundamental answer. Thanks!